# How to assign new values to a tensorflow constant?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am loading a TensorFlow model from a .pb file. I want to change the weights of all the layers. I am able to extract the weights but I am not able to change the weights.

I converted the graph_def model to TensorFlow model but even then I cannot assign a new value to the weights as the weights are stored in a tensor of type "Const".

```
b = graph_tf.get_tensor_by_name("Variable_1:0")      
tf.assign(b, np.ones((1,1,64,64)))
```

I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'assign'
```

Please provide a way to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way you can achieve something like that. You want to replace some constant operations with variables initialized to the value of those operations, so you can first extract those constant values, and then create the graph with the variables initalized to those. See the example below.

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Example graph
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    inp = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 3], name='Input')
    w = tf.constant([[1.], [2.], [3.]], tf.float32, name='W')
    out = tf.squeeze(inp @ w, 1, name='Output')
    gd = tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def()

# Extract weight values
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    w, = tf.graph_util.import_graph_def(gd, return_elements=['W:0'])
    # Get the constant weight values
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        w_val = sess.run(w)
    # Alternatively, since it is a constant,
    # you can get the values from the operation attribute directly
    w_val = tf.make_ndarray(w.op.get_attr('value'))

# Make new graph
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    # Make variables initialized with stored values
    w = tf.Variable(w_val, name='W')
    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    # Import graph
    inp, out = tf.graph_util.import_graph_def(
        gd, input_map={'W:0': w},
        return_elements=['Input:0', 'Output:0'])
    # Change value operation
    w_upd = w[2].assign([5.])
    # Test
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init_op)
        print(sess.run(w))
        # [[1.]
        #  [2.]
        #  [3.]]
        sess.run(w_upd)
        print(sess.run(w))
        # [[1.]
        #  [2.]
        #  [5.]]
```